# subsets of solutions for matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For matrix $A,B$ belonging to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ let $S_A$ be the the solution set for the homogenous system $Ax=0$.

this question has a few parts and I am not really sure how to go about it in a formal proof so I will just provide one of them. This is homework so hints will also be great:)

1. prove or disprove that the $S_{AB}$ is a subset of $S_B$.

Comment: This isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $Ax=0$ then $x$ is in the kernel of $A$ denoted by $\ker A$ and the question is to prove that
$$\ker AB\subset\ker B$$
which is **not true** and we have in fact the contrary:
$$\ker B\subset\ker AB$$

Comment: ok but the next one is kerAB is a subset of kerA which is true, right? and how do I write a formal proof?

Comment: To write a proof: let $x\in \ker B$ so $Bx=0$ then $ABx=A(Bx)=A0=0$ so?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in$ ker$ AB$ then $AB(x)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $A(Bx)=0$ and hence $Bx\in$ ker $A$. So, even ker $(AB)\subset$ ker $A$ is not true.